# Connected Components of Covering Space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, covering-spaces

*Let $\pi : \tilde M\to M$ be a covering map, $K_1, K_2\subset\tilde M$ are two different connected components and there exists such points $x\in K_1, y\in K_2$ that $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$. In other words, $\pi(K_1)\cap\pi(K_2)\neq\varnothing.$*

Is it true that in this instance $\pi(K_1)=\pi(K_2)$?

Give me only an answer and a hint, but not full proof. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If we are talking about path-connectedness, this should be quite simple using the path lifting property.

Comment: I keep wondering if the fact that $\pi(K_1\cup K_2)=\pi(K_1)\cup\pi(K_2)$ is connected is somehow useful.

Comment: Another thought: Can you apply Zorn to produce a maximal evenly covered neighborhood?